# how to find documents that their specific field is not in array type?

Tags: arrays, mongodb

Consider documents below:

```
{'name': 'A', 'link':'All'},
{'name': 'B', 'link':['All','1','2']},
{'name': 'C', 'link':['All']}
```

I want to find all documents which have field 'link' with type of "string" and value of 'All'. I mean I'm not looking for links in array type.
so I want to see the result below:

```
{'name': 'A', 'link':'All'}
```

I tried query below but it didn't work and it returns all document which have 'All' either type is string or array.

```
{link:'All',link:{$type:"string"}}
```

Actually $type operator looks inside the array field not the field itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may fits you,

Avoiding array objects by checking first element of each link value.

```
db.getCollection('yourCollection').find({'link.0': {$exists: false}, link: {$type: 2}})
```

type "2" - means string.